# Имеется код на языке python, необходимо обернуть его в графический интерфейс

Tags: python, tkinter, pymysql

```
import pymysql
from config import host, user, passw, db_name
try:
    connection = pymysql.connect(
        host=host,
        port=3306,
        user=user,
        password=passw,
        database=db_name,
        cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
    )
    print("успех")


    def new_oper():
        input_sum = input("Введите сумму: ")
        if action == "внесение":
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                operation = 'INSERT INTO oper (num_card, type, money, oper_date) VALUES (' + str(
                    input_number_card) + ', "+", ' + str(input_sum) + ',CURRENT_TIME);'
                cursor.execute(operation)
                connection.commit()
        elif action == "снятие":
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                info = 'SELECT num_card,balance FROM `cards` WHERE num_card = 6381592740563821'
                cursor.execute(info)
                rows = cursor.fetchall()
                balance = rows[0]["balance"]
                if float(balance) < float(input_sum):
                    print("Не хватает средств на счету")
                else:
                    operation = 'INSERT INTO oper (num_card, type, money, oper_date) VALUES (' + str(
                        input_number_card) + ', "-", ' + str(input_sum) + ',CURRENT_TIME);'
                    cursor.execute(operation)
                    connection.commit()
        interfeic()

#фунция по получению информации по карте
    def zapros_info():
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            info = 'SELECT num_card,balance FROM `cards` WHERE num_card = 6381592740563821'
            cursor.execute(info)
            rows = cursor.fetchall()
            print(type(rows))
            num_card = print(rows[0]["num_card"])
            balance = print(rows[0]["balance"])
            last_opers = 'SELECT type, money, oper_date FROM `oper` WHERE num_card = 6381592740563821 LIMIT 5;'
            cursor.execute(info)
            cursor.execute(last_opers)
            rows = cursor.fetchall()
            for row in rows:
                if row["type"] == "+":
                    print("Внесение ", row['money'], row['oper_date'])
                else:
                    print("Снятие ", row['money'], row['oper_date'])
            interfeic()
#функция снятия/внесения

    def login():
        global input_number_card
        input_number_card = input("CARD:")
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            log_info = 'SELECT pin FROM `cards` WHERE num_card = '+str(input_number_card)
            cursor.execute(log_info)
            rows = cursor.fetchall()
            block = blocked_card()
            true_pin = rows[0]["pin"]
            print(true_pin)
            if str(input("PIN:")) == str(true_pin) and block != True:
                interfeic()
            elif block == True:
                print("Карта заблокирована")
                login()
            else:
                i = 1
                print("Неправильный PIN\n" + "Количество попыток: " + str(3-i))
                while input("PIN:") != true_pin:
                    i +=1
                    print("Неправильный PIN\n" + "Количество попыток: " + str(3-i))
                    if i == 3:
                        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                            for_block = 'UPDATE cards SET status = "freeze" WHERE num_card = ' + str(input_number_card)
                            cursor.execute(for_block)
                            connection.commit()
                            print("Карта заблокирована")
                            login()

    def blocked_card():
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            info = 'SELECT status FROM cards WHERE num_card = ' + str(input_number_card)
            cursor.execute(info)
            rows = cursor.fetchall()
            stat = rows[0]["status"]
            if stat == 'freeze' or stat == 'block':
                return True
            else:
                return False
    def interfeic():
        print("Ваше действие:")
        global action
        action = input()
        if action == "информация по карте":
            zapros_info()
        elif action == "внесение":
            new_oper()
        elif action == "снятие":
            new_oper()
        elif action == "вернуть карту":
            login()
    login()


except Exception as ex:
    print("Connection...")
    print(ex)
```

Имеется графический интерфейс, но не понимаю, как это соединить, поскольку интерфейс писал одногруппник:

```
import tkinter as tk

class ATMInterface:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.geometry("400x300")
        self.input_num_card = None
        self.input_pin = None
        self.num_card = "1234567890123456"
        self.balance = 1000
        self.last_opers = ["Operation 1", "Operation 2", "Operation 3"]

        self.login()

    def destroy_widgets(self):
        for widget in self.root.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()

    def login(self):
        self.destroy_widgets()
        label = tk.Label(self.root, text="Введите номер карты:")
        label.pack()
        self.input_num_card = tk.Entry(self.root)
        self.input_num_card.pack()
        button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Далее", command=self.enter_pin)
        button.pack()

    def enter_pin(self):
        self.destroy_widgets()
        label = tk.Label(self.root, text="Введите пин-код:")
        label.pack()
        self.input_pin = tk.Entry(self.root, show="*")
        self.input_pin.pack()
        button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Вход", command=self.interfeic)
        button.pack()

    def interfeic(self):
        self.destroy_widgets()
        label = tk.Label(self.root, text="Главный экран")
        label.pack()
        button1 = tk.Button(self.root, text="Информация по карте", command=self.zapros_info)
        button1.pack()
        button2 = tk.Button(self.root, text="Снятие наличных", command=self.cash_withdrawal)
        button2.pack()
        button3 = tk.Button(self.root, text="Внесение наличных", command=self.cash_deposit)
        button3.pack()
        button4 = tk.Button(self.root, text="Вернуть карту", command=self.login)
        button4.pack()

    def zapros_info(self):
        self.destroy_widgets()
        label1 = tk.Label(self.root, text="Номер карты: {}".format(self.num_card))
        label1.pack()
        label2 = tk.Label(self.root, text="Баланс: {}".format(self.balance))
        label2.pack()
        label3 = tk.Label(self.root, text="Последние операции:")
        label3.pack()
        for oper in self.last_opers:
            label_oper = tk.Label(self.root, text=oper)
            label_oper.pack()
        button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Назад", command=self.interfeic)
        button.pack()

    def cash_withdrawal(self):
        self.destroy_widgets()
        label = tk.Label(self.root, text="Введите сумму для снятия:")
        label.pack()
        entry = tk.Entry(self.root)
        entry.pack()
        button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Главный экран", command=self.interfeic)
        button.pack()

    def cash_deposit(self):
        self.destroy_widgets()
        label = tk.Label(self.root, text="Введите сумму для внесения:")
        label.pack()
        entry = tk.Entry(self.root)
        entry.pack()
        button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Главный экран", command=self.interfeic)
        button.pack()

root = tk.Tk()
app = ATMInterface(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: А вопрос то какой, что конкретно не получается?

Comment: Нужно, чтобы в графической интерфейсе выполнялись все функции верхнего кода

Comment: То что вам нужно я понял, но это не вопрос. Что конкретно у вас не получается, что уже пробовали сделать(где это?), какие-то ошибки - в чем проблема?

Comment: Вцелом не понимаю, как это соединить. Пробовал добавлять в интерфейс функции, но пишет, что не заданы переменные

Comment: И как вам тогда помочь, за вас домашку сделать? Тут портал немного про другое...

Comment: Да никто не просит сделать домашку, хочется, чтобы показали как это соединить, на примере или на части кода

Comment: Ну допустим, мы начинаем с нуля. Оборачивайте старый код в отдельные функции (например, подключение к базе, запросы к ней и т.д.) Везде, где ожидается ввод от пользователя — добавляете поле ввода, рядом допустим кнопку, при нажатии на которую должен выполняться код, который идет после ответа пользователя в старом коде. Ну и так далее, постепенно переделываете. Подключение к базе — опять же, при нажатии на какую-то кнопку или при старте программы.